# Highlight selected bar in a column chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have got a column chart with 79 geographies and a slicer with the 79 geographies. The column chart is NOT dependent on the slicer however there are other visualisations in the page that are dependent on the slicer.

What I would to achieve is when I select a specific geography in the slicer the bar that corresponds to that selected geography should be highlighted (i.e. a different colour fill). Can someone please let me know if it is possible to achieve.

I was able to achieve this partly by creating an independent slicer. Not coming from the table or joined to the table. I created 2 new measures, one that shows the selected value in the slicer and the second measure to give it a colour. I used this to change the data colour by using "fx" to determine the colour of the column. I am attaching the Power BI file that shows this solution for your reference.

But by doing an independent slicer my other visualisations don't update. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this without creating an independent slicer so that my other visualisations are not affected.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Measure 1: `Measure = SELECTEDVALUE(Locality[Locality])`

Measure 2: `Colour = IF(MAX(Sheet1[Locality]) = selectedvalue(Locality[Locality]),"red","blue")`

Please see below the screenshot and also link to the sample .pbix file for your reference.

Sample Power BI file - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gqhykbbmeMfFYlChCw?e=w6UABf

Disconnected table solution file - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gql1_KvyEK82cZZDMw?e=7TAR6i

[image: Sample screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a great trick as I checked your solution file. But slicer not working as expected which is your issue as per your explanation. To make it work, you can just think **reverse** of what you have done now.

You have separated slicer value from other data, so that selecting a value in the slicer still keep all Locality in the Bar chart. But problem is, its also keeping all localities in other charts where you wants to take effect of slicer selection. Right?

If the above explanation and assumption is correct, just separate your **Locality** and **Population** column to a different **island (no relation) table**. And create your BAR chart from the new table. Now, if you select a value in the slicer, all charts will be filtered accordingly but the BAR chart.

Finally, apply the Color measure to FX as you implemented currently. This will work as I tried it here and got success. Following is the sample output-

[image]

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, thanks for the solution. I tried what you have said but it is not working for me. I have created a new island (no relations) table with Locality and Population fields. Then I created the Bar chart from this table. I created the two measures based on the Locality table. When I apply the Colour measure to FX it is changing the colour for all the bars. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Can you please help. Here is the link to the current version of the Power BI file. Thank you. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gql2mTQo1oIfVCYHrQ?e=DZCoMA

Comment: Hi @PVS, please check your updated report - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b0UeEHarCAOq3rwqcTWwNm5iC67L3Gni/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is a page level filter on locality. I just decreased the number of value in slicer for testing purpose. Remove that first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. On quick look I noticed that you did not use the Locality table. You made a disconnected table with locality and population fields from "Sheet1" and created the measures for Colour and applied the FX. I will try to recreate this example with my full dataset and updated you if there are any errors.